# Creating an xml file w/ google app engine

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, datastore

I m currently using db.Model to store a string (already in xml format) how do I make this xml string publicly accessible (in the form of example.appspot.com/xml_file so firefox will recgonize it as xml or even of example.appspot.com) I see there is a function to_xml() but I dont know how to use it in such a way that firefox will recognize it as xml??
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Set the response content type to "text/xml".

If you're using GAE's `webapp` framework use this in the request handler:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
```

If you're using another framework, like Django, look up setting the content type in their docs.